# Use macros for line styles in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, macros

I'm working on a paper that has a LARGE number of graphs.  In order to make things manageable, I'm wanting to use LaTeX macros for line styles for maintainability purposes.  However, whenever I try to do this, I get the following:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand{\linestyleA}[0]{color=black!100,mark=star}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=Cost,
        ylabel=Error]
    \addplot[\linestyleA{}] coordinates {
        (2,-2.8559703)
        (3,-3.5301677)
        (4,-4.3050655)
        (5,-5.1413136)
        (6,-6.0322865)
        (7,-6.9675052)
        (8,-7.9377747)
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I do this, I get an error at line 22:

```
! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `color=black'.  See the xcolor package documentation for explanation.
```

I'm sure there's a easy fix for this, but I can't see it for the life of me.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a `style` with `\tikzset`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\tikzset{linestyleA/.style={color=black!100,mark=star}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=Cost,
        ylabel=Error]
    \addplot[linestyleA] coordinates {
        (2,-2.8559703)
        (3,-3.5301677)
        (4,-4.3050655)
        (5,-5.1413136)
        (6,-6.0322865)
        (7,-6.9675052)
        (8,-7.9377747)
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]